# Consciente de que / consciente que

Tags: uso-de-palabras, selección-de-palabras, preposiciones, queísmo-dequeísmo

En las siguientes dos oraciones, ¿cuál es correcta?

1. Soy consciente **que** la deuda es muy grande para mí.
2. Soy consciente **de que** la deuda es muy grande para mí.

Pongo en negrilla las palabras con las cuales tengo duda. Ambas suenan bien para mí, pero no estoy seguro de ello.

Comment: Mira [esta pregunta](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/11964/5481). Si bien la pregunta no es la misma [la respuesta te puede ayudar](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/11965/5481)

Comment: Cuando tengas duda de si debes/puedes usar la preposición "de" convierte la frase en una pregunta (Mira el punto 3 de [este artículo de la RAE sobre _dequeísmo_](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=vTr05If13D6tGOqCWV)). Si la pregunta debe empezar con la preposición entonces tu frase debe llevarla. Preguntarías "**De** qué soy consciente?" o "Qué soy consciente?"

Comment: Is your question about the difference between que and de que???

Comment: @Tia27, the question is if that "de" can or should be there. He is asking if both sentences are correct or which one is correct in case only one sentence is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La mejor opción en este caso es "Soy consciente **de** que la deuda es muy grande para mí", ¿por qué? Simplemente preguntate a tí mismo.

Muchas veces la respuesta a una duda gramatical se puede resolver haciendose preguntas a uno mismo, en este caso deberías preguntarte "¿De qué soy consciente?" El mismo ejemplo se puede usar para una graaaaaan cantidad de problemas similares.

Answer (score 6):

La RAE responde a esa misma pregunta en [su cuenta de Twiter](https://twitter.com/RAEinforma/status/423797668750819329).

> No debe elidirse la preposición DE en la expresión SER CONSCIENTE DE ALGO: «Soy consciente **de** que tengo un reto»

Cuando tengas duda de si estás haciendo un uso indebido de la preposición "de" (*dequeísmo*) sigue [esta recomendación de la RAE](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=vTr05If13D6tGOqCWV) y convierte la frase en una pregunta. Si la pregunta debe empezar con la preposición entonces tu frase debe llevarla.

> ¿De qué se preocupa? (Se preocupa **de** que...)
>
> ¿De qué está seguro? (Está seguro **de** que...)
>
> ¿Qué opina? (Opina que...);

Preguntarías "**De** qué soy consciente?" o "Qué soy consciente?". Hay verbos que tienen que llevar la preposición. El no usarla puede resultar en el fenómeno opuesto el *queísmo*.