# Quedé triste que te fueras - verb tense

Tags: verbos, subjuntivo

Are both sentences below correct?

- Quedé triste que te fuiste.
- Quedé triste que te fueras.

[Google Translate](http://translate.google.com) and [DeepL translator](https://www.deepl.com/en/translator) gave me the 2nd sentence, which makes me think it is more usual. Is it indeed?

Why is the subjunctive used in the 2nd sentence?

Comment: They sound weird. I'd say *Me quedé triste cuando te fuiste* and *Me quedaría triste si te fueras*. In the first it is a fact that *you left* and the second there is only a possibility that *you would leave*

Comment: I guess it is the same as in portuguese. *Fiquei triste quando... / Ficaria triste se você fosse embora.  *

Comment: @DGaleano I'm asking about the Spanish equivalent of "Fiquei triste *que* você foi embora" (past + past), which means "Fiquei triste *porque* você foi embora" (Me quedé triste porque te fuiste) and not "Fiquei triste *quando* você foi embora" (Me quedé triste cuando te fuiste)

Comment: Ok. So "Me quedé triste de que te fuiste" or "Me quedé triste porque..."

Comment: @AlanEvangelista You've been probably warned about this already, but remember Port. *ficar* and Sp. *quedar(se)* are not always equivalent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most idiomatic way to say it is

> Me quedé triste porque/cuando te fuiste

which does not require subjunctive because it uses *porque* instead of *que*.

If you want to use *que*, you could also say

> Me quedé triste de que te fueras

which is grammatically correct but is less common ([0 results on Google!](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22qued%C3%A9%20triste%20de%20que%20te%20fueras%22)). [This](http://uni.canuelo.net/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/subjuntivo_formas_y_usos_nvo.pdf) document is a good reference  for when to use subjunctive. See on the second page, *triste + (de) que* requires subjunctive. Note that in this case, you would need *de* to introduce the relative clause. See [this answer](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/32200/24236) for details.

Comment: I see more results in Google of "triste que te fueras" than "triste de que te fueras". I know that is not a measure of correctness, but is the "de" usually dropped in informal speech?

Comment: As "quedé triste de eso" is wrong Spanish, your explanation about why "de" is required in my sentence is very confusing. Could you please improve it?

Comment: @AlanEvangelista you did not google the whole sentence. "Triste que te fueras" can be a part of many correct sentences such as "Me puso triste que te fueras" or "Fue triste que te fueras". If you google "quedé triste de que te fueras", you get 0 results, same as for "quedé triste que te fueras".

Comment: @AlanEvangelista true, "me quedé triste de eso" sounds weird, one would definitely say "me quedé triste por eso". It looks like none of the "tricks" for "que" vs "de que" suggested in https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/61/when-to-use-que-and-de-que works in all cases. I removed the link to that question and linked to your new question instead, as I do not have a better reason than "it is just like that with triste"...

Comment: Most everybody drops the *de* in this kind of sentence and others (*queísmo*) even though it's formally wrong.