# triste de/por/con

Tags: preposiciones

I have been recently told that

> Me quedé triste de eso

is idiomatic in Spanish. Are "por" and "con" correct and usual instead of "de" in this context? Examples:

- Me quedé triste por eso.
- Me quedé triste con eso.

Comment: If this is related to your previous question and the answer you got, it is good to link that for completeness. Also, it is also useful to provide feedback to that answer to clarify, since it was wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Me quedé triste **de** eso.

is not a correct sentence in Spanish.

What you were told [here](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/32196/qued%C3%A9-triste-que-te-fueras-verb-tense) is that, when followed by a "que"-clause, you need "de". When the clause is a complement, "de" is actually required:

- Estoy triste **de** que te vayas.
- Estoy feliz **de** que vengas.
- Estoy contento **de** que hayas ganado.

However, "de" is incorrect when the clause is the subject:

- Me pone triste que te vayas (= Que te vayas me pone triste.)
- Me pone feliz que vengas (= Que vengas me pone feliz.)
- Me pone contento que hayas ganado (= Que hayas ganado me pone contento.)

"de" is also usual when what follows is an infinitive:

- Estoy triste **de** saber que te vas.
- Estoy feliz **de** saber que venís (Arg) / **de** saber que vienes.
- Estoy contento **de** saber que ganaste.

However, when what follows is a noun, other prepositions will be idiomatic:

- Estoy triste **por** tu partida.
- Estoy triste **con** tu partida.
- Estoy feliz **por** tu visita.
- Estoy feliz **con** tu visita.
- Estoy contento **por** tu éxito.
- Estoy contento **con** tu éxito.
  (In all of these cases, "por" might be preferred.)